# Parse xml element attribute using minidom python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have to parse an xml which has xml elements with attributes whose values can be multiline with spaces and line breaks.

I am parsing using minidom but the multiline attribute values which i am getting are not having line breaks.

How to get such values using minidom? If not minidom which other library supports such attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the matter of `minidom` or whatever-dom. It is `XML` standard, who tells that attribute value

> For a white space character (#x20, #xD, #xA, #x9), append a space
>   character (#x20) to the normalized value

https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#attdecls

That means, you wont ever find `\n` (linefeed), `\r` (carriage return) or `\t` (tab) character in the value of XML attribute, at least if your parser follows the rules.

Answer (score 0):

According to [XML-Spec - 3.3.3 Attribute-Value Normalization](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize) newlines are not allowed and get replaced by spaces.

> Before the value of an attribute is passed to the application or
>   checked for validity, the XML processor must normalize the attribute
>   value by applying the algorithm below, or by using some other method
>   such that the value passed to the application is the same as that
>   produced by the algorithm.
>
> 1. All line breaks must have been normalized on input to #xA as described
>      in 2.11 End-of-Line Handling, so the rest of this algorithm operates
>      on text normalized in this way.
> 2. Begin with a normalized value consisting of the empty string.
> 3. For each character, entity reference, or character reference in the
>      unnormalized attribute value, beginning with the first and continuing
>      to the last, do the following:
>
>    - For a character reference, append the referenced character to the
>        normalized value.
>    - For an entity reference, recursively apply step 3 of this algorithm to
>        the replacement text of the entity.
>    - For a **white space character** (#x20, **#xD, #xA,** #x9), append a space
>        character (#x20) to the normalized value.
>    - For another character, append the character to the normalized value.

(emphasis mine)

See [open "bug" *xml.dom.minidom does not escape CR, LF and TAB characters within attribute values*](http://bugs.python.org/issue5752) as well)